# How to assign different colors to each bar in react apext chart?

Tags: reactjs, npm, bar-chart, apexcharts

I want different colors for different bars in React apex chart. How can achieve it?

Please, find below the snippet for Bar chart which is using to set all properties inside state of reactjs.

I am using the **react-apexchart** npm library.

```
 this.state = {
      series: [{
        data: [422, 413, 93]
      }],
      
      options : {
        chart: {
        height: 200,
        type: 'bar',
      },
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          dataLabels: {
            position: 'center', // top, center, bottom
          },
        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        offsetY: -20,
        style: {
          fontSize: '12px',
          colors: ["#fff"]
        }
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: ['Alerts', 'Service Requests', 'Incidents'],
        position: 'bottom',
        axisBorder: {
          show: false
        },
        axisTicks: {
          show: false
        },
        crosshairs: {
          fill: {
            type: 'gradient',
            gradient: {
              colorFrom: '#D8E3F0',
              colorTo: '#BED1E6',
              stops: [0, 100],
              opacityFrom: 0.4,
              opacityTo: 0.5,
            }
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: true,
        }
      },
      yaxis: {
          show: false
        },
      grid: { show: false, },
      colors: ['#c00000','#000', '#333'],
      title: {
        text: 'ALL HTI Tickets in GSD (928k Tickets YTD)',
        floating: true,
        offsetY: 330,
        align: 'center',
        style: {
          color: '#444',
          fontSize: '14',
          fontWeight: '600'
        }
      }
    } //option
        
        };
```

Answer (score 4):

You just have to add one property as below:
**distributed: true**

```
    this.state = {
          series: [{
            data: [422, 413, 93]
          }],
          
          options : {
            chart: {
            height: 200,
            type: 'bar',
          },
          plotOptions: {
            bar: {
              dataLabels: {
                position: 'center', // top, center, bottom
              },
    distributed: true
            }
          },
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            offsetY: -20,
            style: {
              fontSize: '12px',
              colors: ["#fff"]
            }
          },
          xaxis: {
            categories: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
            position: 'bottom',
            axisBorder: {
              show: false
            },
            axisTicks: {
              show: false
            },
            crosshairs: {
              fill: {
                type: 'gradient',
                gradient: {
                  colorFrom: '#D8E3F0',
                  colorTo: '#BED1E6',
                  stops: [0, 100],
                  opacityFrom: 0.4,
                  opacityTo: 0.5,
                }
              }
            },
            tooltip: {
              enabled: true,
            }
          },
          yaxis: {
              show: false
            },
          grid: { show: false, },
          colors: ['#c00000','#000', '#333'],
          title: {
            text: 'heading',
            floating: true,
            offsetY: 330,
            align: 'center',
            style: {
              color: '#444',
              fontSize: '14',
              fontWeight: '600'
            }
          }
        } //option
            
            };
```

[Run It On Codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/ZEWKggz)